# Stuck on installing Brasero

Tags: software-installation, brasero

```
0% [Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.91.23)]

 Cannot initiate the connection to us.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::16). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
0% [Connecting to security.ubuntu.com (91.189.88.161)]
```

I'm trying to install Brasero as a burner for my DVD, but it doesn't proceed. I tried installing it from ubuntu software as well as in terminal same result. In Ubuntu Software app it says pending forever.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your local repository mirror is currently down, for workaround you can try changing the repository to the **Main Server**, here's how to do it:

1. Open dash then type **Updates**, click/open **Software & Updates** from search result.
2. On **Download From** drop down menu selection, choose **Main Server**.

[image]

3. There will be pop-up asked you to fill your password, once you have type your password click <kbd>Authenticate</kbd> button to apply change you've made.

[image]

4. Close the window then.